# IIS LocalSystem Application pool cannot access my system certificates

Tags: wcf, iis, certificate, signing

I've developed a c# (.NET 4.0) application that signs PDF documents using SecureBlackbox libraries. For my signatures, the signing process uses some installed user certificates from **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** and **Intermediate Certification Authorities**. The signing works when I open my testing application as a user, but when i implement this module in a WCF service on IIS (using **LocalSystem** identity for my Application pool) it doesn't work because it cannot find those certificates.

Note that I've additionally installed those certificates using mmc.exe in Computer account -> Local computer snap-in, but that doesn't solve it. I've also tried to add them to Service account -> Local computer -> World Wide Web Publishing Service (that's IIS, right?), and no success...

Can anyone suggest something else to try? I am not sure at all what IIS is using as account or even if it can access my certificates at all in some other way, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found to be correct is that when you use ApplicationPool with identity LocalSystem, the certificates that belong to the system can be managed with mmc.exe when adding snap-in: Computer account -> Local computer. The actual problem was my bad coding while fetching certificates from system store using SBB library. I've solved that and therefore i've solved the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. You've just said that it was your bad codding while fetching the certificates. how should it be helpful to anyone?

Comment: @AshkanSirous The question that I asked was referencing a problem I struggled with. It's helpful for everyone to know that It's my fault, rather to leave it for vague guesswork

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cert has read permissions for Local System (if that's what your iis process is set up to run).